# Div is overlapping previous div and breaking functionality of previous div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a calculator I built in javascript/html and it expands as inputs are filled. The following `div` is some basic content and share to social media buttons but that content doesn't move up or down because the div seems to be overlapping.

I tried `display:block`, `position:relative`, etc and other variations I found online with all the `div`s involved but I'm not too well-versed with `div` positioning when it comes to dynamic sizing like mine is. How can I make the `div` right after the calculator start after it and not overlap?

The page is: http://www.tasteaholics.com/keto-calculator/

Thank you all very much in advance!

Comment: in general it is better to give us code to look at. Most people won't follow links. I want you to get the help you need so add your code. :-D

Comment: As a side note, I'd definitely make the inputs perform their functions upon 'change' rather than when you focus/blur out of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `clear:both;` to that `div`, this will prevent other elements from floating either on the left or the right side.

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks so much. Now I know what clear does haha